# Функция по событию выполняется сразу при старте

Tags: javascript

Вот просто левый пример. Почему функция, которая должна выполняться по клику, выполняется просто так?

```
button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];

block = document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0];

button.onclick = test();

function test(){
block.style.height = "100px";  
block.style.background = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы присваиваете onclick не функцию, а результат ее выполнения.

Правильно будет:

```
function test(){
  block.style.height = "100px";  
  block.style.background = "red";
}

button.onclick = test;//без скобок
```

или

```
button.onclick = function(){
  block.style.height = "100px";  
  block.style.background = "red";
}
```